# Can I change the order that my symbols load in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I have a Windows Mobile project that runs some code before displaying the first form. If I put a breakpoint on a method I know is called before the form is displayed I get the hollow breakpoint warning symbol that tells me "the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols loaded for this document".

When I look in Debug -> Windows -> Modules the PDB for the dll that contains the method I want to break on is loaded last. The executable which runs the method is already running at this point, and it seems by the time the PDB is loaded the method has finished executing.

Hopefully that all makes sense.

What I really want to know is, is there any way around this? Can I ensure that the PDB loads before my program starts executing?

Comment: That sounds wrong - in my experience, admittedly not with mobile, VS loads all symbols before it starts executing. What happens if you start your code with F10 and give it time to load symbols before running again?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about starting debugging with F10, very useful. 

However, that doesn't seem to solve my problem. It seems around half of the pdb's are loaded when I start the app with F10, and they don't continue to load until I press F5 to continue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before in completely random situations. IE, it just stopped working.

I've also had it vanish by cleaning, rebuilding, restarting visual studio and at in some instances rebooting sorted it.

Comment: Unfortunately none of those suggestions have worked. I'm starting to wonder if it's a project setting that has been changed in the repo, as I can't remember this happening in the past.